# Why I can't retrieve the content of a select tag in this JavaScript\JQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not so into JavaScript and JQuery and I have the following problem trying to retrieve the value inserted into a **select** tag defined into my page.

So into a page I have this **select** tag:

```
<select id="idAnnoRiferimento" onchange="setDataRicAgevolazione(this.value)" style="width: 150px; text-align: center" name="">
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
    <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
</select>
```

Then into a JavaScript function I want to retrieve the selected value, so I tryed to do something like this:

```
function controlloDate() {
    alert("INTO controlloDate()");

    var annoDiRiferimento = $("#idAnnoRiferimento").innerHTML;
    alert("Anno di riferimento: " + annoDiRiferimento);

    ............................................................
    DO SOME OTHER STUFF
    ............................................................
}
```

So, as you can see, I tryed to retrieve the select tag having **id=idAnnoRiferimento** and from this tag I tryed to retrieve the inner value by the use of the **innerHTML** properties but the alert show me a message that say **undefined**.

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`innerHTML`, is a javascript property which won't work on jquery objects,

use `$("#idAnnoRiferimento").val()` to get changed value, or `$("#idAnnoRiferimento").html()` get get inner html.

To access these properties in the javascript way, you need to get the javascript element object,

```
$("#idAnnoRiferimento")[0].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery object returned from the selector does not have an `innerHTML` property - that's part of a native DOMElement. Instead, you can try `html()`:

```
var annoDiRiferimento = $("#idAnnoRiferimento").html();
```

Note that if you're attempting to get the value of the selected option, use `val()`:

```
var annoDiRiferimento = $("#idAnnoRiferimento").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

In jquery `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea

In an HTML document, `.html()` can be used to get the contents of any element.

Answer (score 1):

javascript code:

```
var e = document.getElementById("idAnnoRiferimento");
var sel = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the innerHTML, you want the value.

```
$("#idAnnoRiferimento").val()
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple use this in jQuery

```
jQuery('#idAnnoRiferimento option:selected').val()
```

and @RoryMcCrossan & @ShrutiKarekal answer is working with out jQuery

```
var e = document.getElementById("idAnnoRiferimento"); 
var sel = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function:

```
$("#idAnnoRiferimento").val()
```